# React.js states won't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a simple React app that I am going to post entirely (it is not that long). The app doesn't work but doesn't throw any error either. I tried to log the states and it turns out they never change. I am using *big things* like custom hook and useReducer, but I suspect I lack on understanding basic principles of how react works.

Here's a short summary of how the app should work:
There is a `Form` component which returns a series of custom `Input` elements (here only two).
The `Input` component outsources the validation logic to a custom hook which returns `[isTouched, isValid, dispatcherOfTheCustomHookReducer]`. When an event occurs, the `Input` component calls the dispatcher of the custom hook and then styles should be applied to the `<input>` element based on the state returned by the reducer in the custom hook.
Also since the Form component needs to know if the form as a whole is valid, each Input has an `onChangeValidity` property used to lift up the `isValid` state.
In theory the form should appear neutral at the beginning and then, after you focus and blur an input this should become either valid (blue background) or invalid (red background).
I should probably reset the inputs after submission and add something else, but for now I want to make the app work. At the moment the states never changes and the forms appears always neutral (white).

You may prefer look at the files in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-glitter-gum4e?file=/src/components/use-validation.js).

App.js

```js
import Form from './components/Form';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Form />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Form.js

```js
import { useReducer } from 'react';

import Input from './Input';

// put your inputs' ID here to generate the default state
const defaultState = (inputs = ['username', 'email']) => {
  let inputsState = {};
  for (const input of inputs) inputsState[input] = false;
  return { ...inputsState, isValid: false };
};

const formReducer = (state, action) => {

  let newInputsStateList = {...state, [action.id]: action.isValid};
  delete newInputsStateList.isValid;

  let isValid = true;
  for(const key in newInputsStateList) {
    if(!newInputsStateList[key]) isValid = false;
    break;
  }

  return { ...newInputsStateList, isValid};
}

const Form = props => {

  const [formState, dispatchFormState] = useReducer(formReducer, undefined, defaultState);

  const submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('You are logged in.');
  }

  return <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>

    <Input
      id='username'
      label='Username'
      type='text'
      test={username => username.trim().length > 6}
      onChangeValidity={validity => dispatchFormState({id: 'username', isValid: validity})}
    />

    <Input
      id='email'
      label='Email'
      type='email'
      test={email => email.includes('@')}
      onChangeValidity={validity => dispatchFormState({id: 'email', isValid: validity})}
    />

    <button type='submit' disabled={!formState.isValid} >Submit</button>
  </form>
};

export default Form;
```

Input.js

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import classes from './Input.module.css';
import useValidation from '../hooks/use-validation';

const Input = props => {

  const [isTouched, isValid, checkValidity] = useValidation();

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  useEffect(() => props.onChangeValidity(isValid), [isValid]);

  return <div className={classes.generic_input}>
    <label className={classes['generic_input-label']} htmlFor={props.id} >{props.label}</label>
    <input
      className={classes[`${isTouched ? 'generic_input-input--'+isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid' : ''}`]}
      type={props.type}
      name={props.id}
      id={props.id}
      onChange={event => checkValidity({
        type: 'CHANGE',
        value: event.target.value,
        test: props.test
      })}
      onBlur={event => checkValidity({
        type: 'BLUR',
        value: event.target.value,
        test: props.test
      })}
    />
  </div>
};

export default Input;
```

use-validation.js

```js
import { useReducer } from 'react';

const validationReducer = (state, action) => {

  let isTouched = state.isTouched;
  let isValid = state.isValid;

  if(action.type === 'CHANGE') if (isTouched) isValid = action.test(action.value);

  else if(action.type === 'BLUR') {

    isValid = action.test(action.value);

    if (!isTouched) isTouched = true;
  }

  else isTouched = isValid = false;

  return {isTouched, isValid};
}

const useValidation = () => {

  const [validationState, dispatchValidation] = useReducer(validationReducer, {isTouched: false, isValid: false});

  return [validationState.isTouched, validationState.isValid, dispatchValidation];
};

export default useValidation;
```

Input.module.css

```css
.generic_input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.generic_input-label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.generic_input-input--valid {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.generic_input-input--invalid {
  border-color: red;
  background-color: rgb(250, 195, 187);
}

.submit:disabled {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #292929;
  border-color: #CCC;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: create it on codesandbox . it will be easy to debug

Comment: @SwordI I never used it, I am going to try

Comment: I did it. Here is the [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-glitter-gum4e?file=/src/components/use-validation.js). I noticed a difference with what I got in the browser: in codesandbox the submit button has the `disabled` style always applied while in the browser is never applied. In theory it should be applied only when the form is touched and invalid.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mutate your state directly in `validationReducer`.  I think your problem lies there.

Comment: @AliKlein I think the reducer is legit, it is returning a new object.

Comment: `isTouched` never changed so you never reach your `if (isTouched)` in your reducer.

Comment: @AliKlein but in `Input.js` the `<input>` element has a listener for *blur* events which dispatches a new state for the reducer in the hook (`checkValidity` in `Input.js` is an alias of `dispatchValidation` in `use-validation.js`). Then in the reducer, for `BLUR` events, we got `if (!isTouched) isTouched = true;` which sets `isTouched` to `true` after the first time an input is being blurred and we also changed `isValid`  based on the function given to test the validity of the value typed by the user `isValid = action.test(action.value);`. Continues...

Comment: ...At this point since a new state has been dispatched, the Input component should be reevaluated and the `className` of the `<input>` element should change to either `generic_input-input--valid` (blue) or `generic_input-input--invalid` (red). Anyway thank you for trying to help @AliKlein.

Comment: Your `if (!isTouched) isTouched = true;` is inside of the `if (isTouched)` so it never reaches there. Also, your input className should look like: {classes[isTouched ? `generic_input-input--${isValid ? "valid" : "invalid"}` : "" ] }

Comment: Here is your sandbox forked with `isTouched` changing to `true` on change, and the className fixed on your input: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-waterfall-vop71?file=/src/hooks/use-validation.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to fix the `isTouched` logic in your `validationReducer`. `isTouched` never gets set to `true`:

Something like:

```js
const validationReducer = (state, action) => {
  let isTouched = state.isTouched;
  let isValid = state.isValid;

  if (action.type === "CHANGE") {
    isTouched = true;
    isValid = action.test(action.value)
  } else if (action.type === "BLUR") {
    isValid = action.test(action.value);
  } else {
    isTouched = isValid = false;
  }

  return { isTouched, isValid };
};
```

... though I'm not sure when you'd want `isTouched` to be set to false again, so that logic needs some work...

Also, the class on your input is not correct.

Its should look like:

```js
  <input
     className={
       classes[
         isTouched
           ? `generic_input-input--${isValid ? "valid" : "invalid"}`
           : ""
       ]
     }
     ...
   >
```

Take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-waterfall-vop71)

Comment: OMG thank you very so much for making it work! I was so insecure abut my React knowledge that I wasn't expecting the bug to be in the ECMAScript code.
From now I will always use brackets with `if`, ot at least with nested `if`. And yes, I totally failed with that template literal. Thank you again, you saved me I don't know how much time and stress!

Comment: So happy I could help!